# Allocating specific amount of physical memory in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: vb.net, memory, memory-management, ram

I know this is kind of a weird question, but how do you...allocate physical memory? I know using New will make a new object but it's not allocating what I'm looking for. Here's kind of what I'm looking for: http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-memalloc/index.html

That program allocates memory in the way I want to. How would I go about allocating around...say 500 MB? Or will VB.NET not allow this because of it's memory management? I tried googling about memorystreams and unmanagedmemorystreams but I'm not sure how to start. I also tried making large arrays but that seems kind of...unprofessional. I've only been using VB.NET for a year or so. Can someone help me get started? By the way, I just joined. Nice to meet you all!

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate and free a specified block of unmanaged memory like this:

```
Dim handle As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size)
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(handle)
```

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17.aspx) for more info.  You could alternatively use the `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem` method and free it with `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`.

Answer (score 0):

utilize the windows api functions such as [HeapAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/)